# How is the Price Gas increased when calling a function in solidity?

Tags: solidity, smartcontracts, metamask, remix

How is the Price Gas increased when calling a function in solidity ?

I use Remix e Inject Provider - Metamask.

Takes the values ​​set in Metamask ?

Short and clear question.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Solidity code is compiled into EVM-compatible bytecode containing a set of operations. For example `sload` reads from persistent storage, `mstore` saves data to non-persistent memory, etc.

Each of these operations have a fixed cost in gas units. You can find the specific list in the [Yellow paper](https://ethereum.github.io/yellowpaper/paper.pdf), Appendix G.

So to put it simply - the more operations (or more expensive ones) your function uses, the higher is the resulting cost in gas units.

Each network then has some gas price, which is the amount of ETH (or whichever native currency the network uses - for example BNB on Binance Smart Chain) that you pay for each gas unit. In most public networks, this gas price is driven by market demand and fluctuates over time. In most private networks and emulators, you can configure the static value of gas price... Total amount of gas units multiplied by the current gas price results in the total transaction fees.

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't answer the question about how to increase the amount of gas or the price of gas in a contract function call.

Comment: @JulioSarda Sorry, I misunderstood your question at first... The user sends the transaction first, specifying all of its params, including the gas limit and gas price - and then (after the transaction has been sent) a miner/validator executes your contract function and publishes the state changes in a block they produce... So there's no way to affect the transaction params from your contract, as they have already been set and signed before executing the smart contract code.

Comment: how or where including paramaters gas limit and gas price in weth.transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), amountIn);  or in router.swapExactTokensForTokens(
            amountIn,
            amountOutMin,
            path,
            msg.sender,
            block.timestamp
        ); ?

Comment: @JulioSarda If this is Solidity code, then the parameters of the main transaction are used. If this is offchain code (some JS framework for example), then it uses default values (e.g. 0 ETH value) in combination with recommendations from the node that you're connected to (e.g. the `gasPrice` recommended by your node provider).

Comment: I'm going to try in JS add Gas Price to the Main Function call.
And see if this impacts transactions.
Thank you !!